# How To convert Postgres pgBlob to SerialBlob?

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, orm, blob

I am trying to save and retrieve JPA Entity having a blob attribute in Postgres.

When trying to retrieve the entity from the database, I am getting `pgblob` (`org.postgresql.jdbc.PgBlob@48bf4bca`) instead of a `serial blob` (`javax.sql.rowset.serial.SerialBlob`).

I need serial blob to do my functionality so need to convert `pgblob` (instance of postgress) to `serialblob`. How can I do this?

Why is Postgres giving me `pgBlob` instead of `serialblob`?

My `orm.xml` looks like:

```
<basic attribute-type="java.sql.Blob" name="clobAttr">
            <column length="1500" name="clobAttrPersist"/>
        </basic>
```

and the blob data in postgres is stored as `oid`.